# How to determine all the complex structures on torus $T^2$?

Tags: complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I have known that the lattice given by the pair $(\tau_1,\tau_2)$ can determine a complex structures on torus $T^2$.

**But how to prove that all the complex structures of torus can be obtained in this way?**

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099043/complex-structures-on-a-real-torus

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the [Riemann mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem#Classification_of_compact_Riemann_surfaces).

If you consider a compatible Riemannian metric on the torus, the claim can be expressed as follows: every metric on the torus has a flat metric in its conformal class.